# Hard disk not visible on dual boot system after reinstalling GRUB

Tags: 12.04, hard-drive

My hard disk is not visible to me, I am using 12.04 with parallel Windows XP. First I install 12.04 then I installed Windows XP. Ubuntu GRUB menu is hidden. I then repaired Ubuntu. On that time hard disk is not visible to me. Please help.

Comment: Installing Windows after Ubuntu will wipe out grub that is why grub was lost when you reboot after Windows installation. What did you use to repair Ubuntu? Have you tried boot-repair? What do you exactly mean by hard disk not visible? Try checking with Disk Utility or GParted.

Comment: in my system disk utility is also not open.please help me step by step process.Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to install Boot repair

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: i repaired my ubuntu 12.04 this site